# Is $f(x)=x^2-4x$ injective and surjective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

If $f: A\to \mathbb{R}$ be such that $f(x) = x^2 - 4x$, where $A = \{x ∈ \mathbb{R}: x \ge 2\}$.

How do I determine if the following function is injective or surjective and has an inverse?

Here's my attempt:
domain: $\mathrm{dom} (f) = [2,\infty)$, co-domain: $(-\infty,\infty) = \mathbb R$.

Let $a, b \in  A$. Then
\begin{align}
f (a) = f(b) &\Rightarrow a^2 - 4a = b^2  - 4b \\
&\Rightarrow a^2 - b^2 - 4a + 4b = 0 \\
&\Rightarrow(a + b)(a - b) - 4(a - b) = 0 \\
&\Rightarrow(a - b)(b - 4) = 0 \\
&\Rightarrow a - b = 0 \text{ or }a + b -4 = 0 \\
&\Rightarrow a = b \text{ or }a + b = 4.
\end{align}
Therefore, f is injective.
Then I become stuck.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189)
Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others
there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people
will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation,
and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting only in the title.

Comment: One thing I like about this question is the phrasing "How do I determine..." is asking for methods instead of specific solutions. Thus we can answer by giving hints in what direction to think. This is far better than asking "Is it the case, that... and why?" -- Nevertheless you should still always include some description of the attempts you have undertaken and where you got stuck.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to know whether or not you know calculus so that responses can be addressed to your skill level.

Comment: For these types of problems, begin with the definitions of injection and surjection to construct a proof. I've provided some examples where the definitions are used to prove or disprove that a given function is injective or surjective. I've also provided a couple hints for your particular problem while restricting myself to the definitions only, and not employing calculus.

Comment: I’m sorry. When I worked out the objective part, I wrote $f(x)=x^2-2x$. It turns out the function is not injective. What you have is good work! Now look at those equations and ask yourself “are there two points $a$ and $b$ such that $a\neqb$ but f(a)=f(b)$? Try $a=0$ and $b=4$. This will show that $f$ is not injective.

Comment: In the line in which you wrote $(a - b)(b - 4) = 0$, you meant to write $(a - b)(a + b - 4) = 0$.

Comment: @ N. F. Taussig. Yes, I just realized that? And why is my question 'On hold'? I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Typical strategies for proving or disproving injection and surjection with examples**

To show that $f$ is injective, begin by assuming that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ where $x_1,x_2 \in A$, and then deduce using algebra that $x_1 = x_2$.

If $f$ is not injective, then you should be able to find two points $x_1,x_2 \in A$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, but $x_1 \neq x_2$. In other words, you are looking for two distinct elements in the domain of $f$ such that they are sent to the same element in the codomain by $f$.

An example of this would be the function $\phi: [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\phi(x) = \sqrt{x}$. This function is not injective, because

$$\phi(-1) = \phi(1) \text{      but      } -1 \neq 1$$

To determine if $f$ is surjective, choose an arbitrary element in the codomain of $f$. That is, let $r \in \mathbb{R}$.

Off to the side, do some scratch work to find the value $a \in A$ such that when you plug $a$ into $f$, you get $r$ back.

For example, suppose I wanted to show that the function $\psi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $\psi(x) = 3x+5$ is surjective.

Choose an arbitrary point $y$ in the codomain of $\psi$ viz. $\mathbb{Z}$.

I went ahead and did some scratch work to find the value of $x$ in the domain of $\psi$, namely $\mathbb{R}$, such that $\psi(x) = r$. That is, I solved
$$\psi(x) = 3x + 5 = y$$
for $x$, and it is
$$ x = \frac{y-5}{3}$$
Then the proof would be like:
Let $y \in \mathbb{Z}$. Choose $x = \frac{y-5}{3}$. Then
\begin{align*}
\psi(x) &= 3x + 5 \\[8pt]
&= 3\bigg(\frac{y-5}{3}\bigg) + 5 \\[8pt]
&= y
\end{align*}
Therefore, $\psi$ is surjective.

To disprove that a function $\rho$ is surjective, we need to find a $y$ in the codomain such that for all $x$ in the domain, the equation $\rho(x) \neq y$.

An example of this would actually be $\phi$ above. Notice that the codomain of $\phi$ is $\mathbb{R}$, so If I were to choose a negative number, say $-7$, then I would have
$$\phi(x) = \sqrt{x} = -7$$
However, there are no $x \in \operatorname{domain}(\phi)$ that makes the above equation true. That is to say, there exists a $y \in \operatorname{codomain}(\phi)$ such that for all $x \in \operatorname{domain}(\phi)$, we have $\phi(x) \neq y$.

Therefore $\phi$ is not surjective.

Another way to look at the concept of surjection is that the range of the function is equal to the function's codomain.

Also a function has an inverse if and only if the function is injective and surjective. Thus $\phi$ does not have an inverse, but $psi$ does (Why? We’ve shown that $\psi$ is surjective. It remains to show that $\psi$ is injective, which can easily be done using the definition.

**Some hints to show that your function is not injective**

Your proof showing that $f$ is injective won’t work, however, it does show you why it doesn’t work.

Look at the equation 
$$a+b=4$$

Then you can choose distinct $a$ and $b$ whose sun is $4$, and it will imply that $f(a)=f(b)$. Thus $f$ is not injective.

For example, we can choose $a=3.5$ and $b=0.5$. Then $f(a)=f(b)=-1.75$, so $f$ can not be injective.

**A hint to show that your function is not surjective**
Often when there is a square, I am often skeptical that the function is surjective, especially when the codomain is $\mathbb{R}$.

So my hint to you is choose $y=-5$. Then show that for $x \in A$, $f(x) \neq -5$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Note that for $x>2$

- $f'(x)=2x-4>0 \implies f$ is injective

then note that

- $x^2-4x+4=(x-2)^2\ge 0 \implies f(x)=x^2-4x\ge -4$

thus $f(x)$ is surjective only on a suitable restriction and in that restriction it is invertible.

Answer (score 0):

It is not surjective (and so does not have an inverse)

The derivative of $f$ is $f'(x)=2x-4$ which is positive for all $x\in A$. It follows that $f$ is an increasing function. Since $f(2)=0$ we have that the function is non-negative. In particular $-1\not\in \text{Range} (f)$ which implies that $f$ is not surjective.

The same argument with the derivative also implies that $f$ is injective (because it is strictly monotone).

Answer (score 0):

THe graph of a quadratic is a parabola and hence a quadratic can be neither injective nor surjective.